# Dynamic height, width and color to canvas fetched from database

Tags: html, css, canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="50" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>    
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 50);
</script>
```

I have a MSSQL database. How to fetch and assign height, width and color property from that database.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? Also, what are the tables and fields inside your database from which you will be getting the height, width, and color?

Comment: I wish to connect in asp .net, and my table have height, width attribute as float and color as varchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

To Connect Mysql Database you use **PHP**

Try this I hope this code help you

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT height, width, color FROM divsize";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
   //create a Canvas     
        echo '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="'.$row["width"].'" height="'.$row["height"].'" style="border:1px solid '.$row["color"].';">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas><br>';        
    }
} else {    
 //create default canvas
    echo '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="50" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>';
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**ASP.NET** and **C#** with **SQL**

**C#**

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");
    string Query = "SELECT height,width,color FROM divsize";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

    var Result = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (Result.HasRows)
    {
       while (Result.Read())
       {
           Dynamicdiv.InnerHtml = "<div style='height:" + Result["height"].ToString() + "px;width:" + Result["width"].ToString() + "px;background-color:" + Result["color"].ToString() + ";'></div >";
       }
    }
    else
    {
       Dynamicdiv.InnerHtml = "<div style='height:100px;width:200px;background-color:red;'></div>";
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
 }
```

**ASP**

```
<div runat="server" id="Dynamicdiv"></div>
```

Comment: I wish to connect in asp .net, and my table have height, width attribute as float and color as varchar(50)

Comment: so you want to done this program in **asp.net** and **c#**

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = prod1color;
ctx.fillRect(prod1tail, 0, prod1head, 50);       prod1color is a string and i am fetching it from database but that color is not coming

Comment: <script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var Color = "green";
ctx.fillStyle = Color;
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
</script>

change color value with hex code or color name